# HTML in category name

Tags: taxonomy, sanitization

how can  edit taxonomy.php in order to stop term sanitizing?
I need HTML (font color) in category name.
Thanks!

Comment: That could cause a lot of issues. Is there a reason you can't use CSS to style your category's name?

Comment: Hi Simone, I support Jack's comment. I would suggest editing the title in the php template after you get it. That way you can do whatever you want with the string and just `echo` it at the end. If you choose this option let us know, I'm sure many will be able to help.

Comment: You can use color picker ACF field, and tie it to the terms. Then in the loop extract this and insert into `style='color: <?php the_field( 'color', 'term_' . $term_id ) ?>'`, check the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/color-picker/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all
@ValentinGenev i choose this option, but i'm totally newbie so i Have to study WP much more in order to follow your lead. I found this in my theme (extras.php):

```
    if ( $child_theme_support == 'default' ) {
        $categories_list = get_the_category_list(esc_html__(', ', 'blossom-fashion-pro'));
    }else{
        $categories_list = get_the_category_list(esc_html__(' ', 'blossom-fashion-pro'));

    }       

    if ($categories_list) {
        echo '<span class="cat-links" itemprop="about">' . $categories_list . '</span>';
    }
}
}
endif;
```

is the right place to edit with something like this?

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_name = 'foo1'; // set this to the category name you want to show
$output = '';
if($categories){
foreach($categories as $category) 
{
        if ( $category_name == $category->cat_name) 
       {
              $output .='<div class="category-custom-class">'.$category->cat_name.'</div>';
       }
       else
       {
             $output .='<div class="category-custom-class1">'.$category->cat_name.'</div>';
       }
}
echo $output;
}
```

I'm sorry to bother you with my ... inexperience! Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi again, I'm sorry for the late response, I didn't receive a notification.
From simply looking at the code, it looks good. There are some things that I would do differently but as far as the programming logic goes it looks good and if it gets the job done, you nailed it!.